# When and why we should do single cluster in a specific layer?

Tags: stata, clustered-standard-errors

From reading [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/230790/319998), there is one sentence

> Standard errors should be clustered at the city level, i.e. the **level
> of aggregation** at which the treatment occurs

In [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300)'s paper, the aggregation level is country (laws have impact on all firms in a country).
I am quite new to cluster standard error but I saw the paper of [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/32/7/2587/5079300), in some cases, he did cluster for the **country** (table 11), in some cases, he did the cluster for **industry** (table 8), in some cases, he did cluster for **firm** (table 12).

I am quite curious about this way of clustering. It is because from [this discussion](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/45435/33142) , it seems that the old "rules of them" is 30-40 groups. However, in Dasgupta's paper case, he has 64 countries and hundreds of thousands of firms, so why he need to cluster for firms and countries?